# ASP.NET ConfirmButtonExtender conditional

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, button, confirmbuttonextender

I have a button on my page (with ajax ConfirmButtonExtender).

If on the page the user has selected over say, 1 million rows of data (this is calculated in the code-behind), when they then click on the the button, a pop up message will ask if they wanted to batch export the selection (i.e. Yes or Cancel).

So essentially, there are 2 possible scenarios.

1) Selection under 1 million rows.
Do NOT show the pop-up confirm message at all when click on the button - just run some codes in code-behind page. (i.e. Bypass the ConfirmButtonExtender msg).

2) Selection over 1 million rows.
A pop up message appears asking user to confirm if they'd like to batch export selection. User will select Yes or Cancel.

My question is - is it possible for the confirm message from ConfirmButtonExtender to be conditional (based on some calculation in the code-behind)?

How do I go about achieving this? Keep in mind that when user first clicks on the button, some codes will first need to run on code-behind to calculate the number of selections then decide whether to prompt the pop-up message.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would really appreciate some tips/advice on how to go about this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, I'm going to skip that query for counting the data rows. But for firing the Confirm Button Extender in the right condition you may simply use this code:

```
if (condition == true)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "notify", "function pageLoad(){$find('YourConfirmButtonExtenderID')._displayConfirmDialog();}", true);
}
else
{
    //do nothing
}
```

Hope its helping you.